# Label in StatusStrip bugging out

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have my `WinForms` application with a `StatusStrip`. Inside this `StatusTrip`, there's a `StatusLabel` (it's **not** the default `Label`, as it's not supported for some reason).

Now, when I set `StatusLabel.IsLink = true;`, you'll get a hand cursor (which is great!). But now, if you do `StatusLabel.Visible = false;` the **whole** `StatusStrip` has a hand cursor on it right now. Making the `StatusLabel` visible again does not fix it.

This seems like either a .NET or C# bug to me.

My question is: is there any workaround for this, I'm not aware of? Either by fixing this hand cursor bug or by placing a **real** `Label` inside the `StatusStrip`? I've found out that when placing a `MessageBox` just right before you make the label non-visible, it's not doing this weird bug.

You can download a test solution [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6166898/StatusLabelBug.zip). In the `Main.cs` file there's a line with the `MessageBox` which you can uncomment. Try it yourself.

Comment: As per the [http://stackoverflow.com/faq](faq) please post code samples in the question rather than links to offsite repositories or downloads.

Comment: the first answer is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the Cursor of your StatusStrip back to Default

```
private void toolStripStatusLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW TO "FIX" IT

    //MessageBox.Show("It's not doing the bug when showing this message.");
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = false;
    statusStrip1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```